# Magento CE 1.8.0.0 on windows 8 and firefox: ordering buttons are not clickable

Tags: magento

it works on win7, but I am on win8 with firefox 38.0.1 (latest). I can't click on "/checkout/onepage/" button. It does work with chrome though..

Does anyone know what's going on ?

Thanks.

Oddly enough, the problem was solved by reparing firefox...

Comment: What is the error are you getting in console log?

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: ReferenceError: decorateGeneric is not defined

Comment: ReferenceError: Accordion is not defined

Comment: ReferenceError: Mage is not defined

Comment: about 10 such comments...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `.js` file for eg. no-conflict.js and add the following content on it:

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And include your no-conflict.js into your theme page.xml file

```
<action method="addJs"><script>no-conflict.js</script></action>
```

Then write your jQuery like as follows

`$j(document).ready(function(){    // write your code here    });`

after including this file into your theme, press `ctrl+U` and view page source. Is all links are working of jQuery. If not then check the path and do correct them.

Comment: sorry, but this is quite confusing...could you specify where in Magento code I should add this ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your javascript is not loading, either permissions errors or the files are inaccessible somehow. This is the head of the checkout/onepage of my install of 1.8. Note that I can open any of the scripts in a new tab:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Checkout</title>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce" />
<meta name="robots" content="*" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://ce-1.8.1.local/skin/frontend/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://ce-1.8.1.local/skin/frontend/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ce-1.8.1.local/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ce-1.8.1.local/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ce-1.8.1.local/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/mage/directpost.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/mage/captcha.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/mage/centinel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/varien/weee.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ce-1.8.1.local/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ce-1.8.1.local/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Mage.Cookies.path     = '/';
Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.ce-1.8.1.local';
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
optionalZipCountries = ["HK","IE","MO","PA"];
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate([]);
        //]]></script>
```